# how does Aws Sagemaker provides multi instance environment and load balancing for endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have successfully deployed my jupyter notebook on AWS Sagemaker,
And have created endpoint for predictive algorithm (Use Case).
I wanted to know how to achieve multi instance environment into AWS Sagemaker and load balancing for multiple request on endpoint.

If the question is not valid please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably created your endpoint like this:

predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                             instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')

If you set initial_instance_count to more than 1, SageMaker automatically assigns that number of instances to your endpoint. Prediction requests will automatically load-balanced, there's nothing else to to.

If needed, you can also set up auto scaling to handle traffic variation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-auto-scaling.html

Comment: Thank you..I ll check this, and let you know.